# Error in n() inside Summarise Function dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

everything good?

During that week I spent time writing a script that even this morning seemed to work. but then I tried to run it again and exactly in a part that uses the function "summarize" of the package dplyr appears an error that I had never seen.

Below is an excerpt of the code I used and the error on the console:

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0)

b <-c(  0.9157101,  
        0.4854955,  
        0.8853174,  
        0.4373646,  
        0.3855175,  
        0.8603407,  
        0.9193342,  
        0.4693117,  
        0.9849855,  
        0.4458159,  
        0.4379776)

c <- c(8,2,7,1,0,6,8,1,9,1,1)

treated_data <- data.frame(Risk = a ,
                           Model_Predicted = b,
                           Grupo = c)

calculo <- treated_data %>% group_by(Grupo) %>% summarise(Quantidade = n(),
                                                          Non_event = sum(Risk),
                                                          Event = n() - sum(Risk))

Console Result:
---------------------------------------------------------
Error in n() : argument "vec" is missing, with no default 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Comment: @akrun dplyr_0.8.5

Comment: Though, I have the devel version, the code should work fine as there are no complexities involved.  Can you rerun the code on a fresh R session with only dplyr loaded

Comment: Your `summarise` could be loaded from another package? Try `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: @ila I opened sessionInfo () in R, and there are only tidyverse and rmarkdown packages.

Comment: try on a fresh R session with only dplyr loaded.  May be some masking issue

Comment: @akrunI ran the code in new sessions on Rstudio and R base (Version 4.0.0), on R base it works normally and Rstudio doesn't

Comment: Try calling both `summarise` and `n` from `dplyr` with `dplyr:::summarise(Event = dplyr:::n() - sum(Risk))` It could be that something in your .Rprofile defines a function `n`.

Comment: @IanCampbell good idea, but `::` is enough - you only need `:::` for functions that a package doesn't export.

Comment: Guys, I restarted the computer, opened a new Rstudio session where I cleared all functions, global parameters and loaded datasets and now the code is working. Thank you for your help!